# Hash code for a rational number

Tags: java

I have implemented a class to model rational numbers in java, it has two integers to model numerator and denominator. I am required to override the hashcode method of Object, so the same numbers have the same hash code.

I have defined my equals() method like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Racional r = null;
    if (obj instanceof Racional) {
        r = (Racional) obj;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return r.getDenominador() * this.numerador == r.getNumerador() * this.denominador;
}
```

Regarding this:

Would returning numerator * denominator be a good approach?

Should equivalent rational numbers (like 1/4 and 2/8) return the same hashcode?

Comment: You could always simplify before computing the hashcode, that way even though the value of the object is 2/8 its hashcode is computed with 1/4

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't it add unnecessary complexity to the hashcode method?

Comment: @EugenioCuevas Catching an exception that could have prevented is generally considered bad practice (throwing / catching an exception is a time consuming operation). It is generally recommended to use `if(obj instanceof Racional)` before the cast to prevent `ClassCastException`s.

Comment: @Jeffrey You are totally right, thanks for that!

Comment: @EugenioCuevas: Whether the complexity is neccessary or unneccessary is something only you can tell.

Comment: You should post your proposed hashCode(). I think there is a possibility of misunderstanding

Comment: it works ... as long as  numerator * denominator don't overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how you implemented your `equals` method. If `obj1.equals(obj2)` is `true`, `obj1.hashCode() == obj2.hashCode()` should also be `true`. I would probably just use `new Double((double) numerator / denominator).hashCode()` for my hash, but your requirements might not allow that.

/edit
Using `numerator * denominator` for your hash would be an invalid approach given your `equals` method. Using your example of `1/4` and `2/8`, `1/4.equals(2/8)` would return `true`, but `1/4.hashCode() == 2/8.hashCode()` would evaluate to `4 == 16`, and return `false`.

Comment: I have added the equals method I already defined, why is the hashcode method depending on it?

Comment: @EugenioCuevas Because that's the way the [`hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) method was defined.

Comment: I tried your solution, only flaw I was expecting was an exception or something for getting the hashcode of infinite or NaN values, but it turns out infinite has a hashcode also, so perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Should equivalent rational numbers (like 1/4 and 2/8) return the same hashcode?

Since your `equals()` method returns `true` for 1/4 and 2/8, [the two numbers must have the same hash code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

One way to achieve this is by simplifying the fraction (for example, at construction time). This can be done by dividing both the numerator and the denominator by their [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor). Once you do this, any reasonable `hashCode()` function would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest something like:

```
37*numerator + 13* denominator
```

for the hashcode, where these are primes.

And I would regard 1/4 and 2/8 as different unless you have an aggressive normalization policy. But this is up to you. Make sure you document the behaviour well.

UPDATE:
You need to decide what equality means.  I would normalize first and then write:

```
return this.numerator == r.numerator && this.denominator == r.denominator
```